# Avoid null values for a specific record

Tags: sql, oracle

How to select all the records from the table, except for null values from value-431 in col-B?

```
COLUMN-A COLUMN-B
--------------------
N       433
N       431
Y       431
        431
        431
Y       431
N       431
N       520
        520
N       304
        390
N       410
        433
```

Desired Output:

```
COLUMN-A COLUMN-B 
-------------------- 
N        433 
N        431 
Y        431 
Y        431 
N        431 
N        520 
         520 
N        304 
         390        
N        410 
         433
```

Comment: Except for NULL in A or B? And what does " from value-431 in col-B" mean?

Comment: my solution should look like this
COLUMN-A    COLUMN-B
--------------------
N           433
N           431
Y           431

Y           431
N           431
N           520
            520
N           304
            390
N           410
            433

Comment: I inserted your desired results into the question. Please verify and edit them if that isn't want you meant. I pasted from the comment and forwarded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:--

```
Select * from 
(select * from table where column_b = 431 and column_a is not null
 union all
 select * from table where column_b <> 431) A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(select * from table where column_b ! - 431 )
union 
(select * from table where column_b = 431 and column_a is not null);
```

Comment: I just want to avoid null values for value 431 in column B

Answer (score 0):

You could write:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column_b <> 431
OR    column_a IS NOT NULL;
```